# How to select a variable based on string value

Tags: javascript, string, variables

For example:

```
labelsSetOne = [1,1,1,1,1]
labelsSetTwo = [2,2,2,2,2]

const printLabels = set => {
  const set = `labelsSet${set}`
  console.log(set)
}

printLabels('one')
```

One solution is using eval: `eval('labelsSet${set}')` however, we all know eval is not save or accepted by a lot of people, another way is `window['labelsSet${set}']` however, in my case it is not a global variable.

Comment: Why don't you use an Object here? `{one:labelsSetOne, two:labelsSetTwo}`

Comment: Use a data structure, not multiple variables, if you want to select them dynamically and not use a bunch of `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` statements.